# Subtrees of Original Tree

Tags: c++, tree, subtree

I am having problems when I am attempting to :
(1) find the largest info field in the left sub-tree of the root of the original tree
(2) find the smallest info field in the right sub-tree of the root of the original tree.

My code compiles but then it has errors when it executes and I'm unclear of what is happening in my maxleftsubtree() and minrightsubtree() functions. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Tnode {
    public:
        Tnode *left;
        string info;
        Tnode *right;
        Tnode(string info = "", Tnode* left = NULL, Tnode* right = NULL) :
            info(info), left(left), right(right) {}
};
class BST {
    public:
        BST() : theroot(NULL) {}
        void insert(string x);
        void inorderprint();
        void preorderprint();
        void postorderprint();
        void maxstring();
        void minstring();
        void maxleftsubtree();
        void minrightsubtree();
    private:
        void inorderprint(Tnode *p);
        void preorderprint(Tnode *p);
        void postorderprint(Tnode *p);
        void maxstring(Tnode *p);
        void minstring(Tnode *p);
        void maxleftsubtree(Tnode *p);
        void minrightsubtree(Tnode *p);
        void insertleft(Tnode *place, string newval);
        void insertright(Tnode *place, string newval);
        Tnode *theroot;
};

// add a new node (with x as info) to tree that has theroot as root
void BST::insert(string x)
{
    // if the tree is initially empty, put x at the root
    if (theroot==NULL) {
        theroot = new Tnode(x);
        return;
    }

    Tnode *p, *q;

    // otherwise, find where x belongs in the tree
    p = theroot;
    q = theroot;
    while ( q != NULL) {
        p = q;
        if (x < p-> info)
            q = p-> left;
        else
            q = p-> right;
    }

    // to get here, we found the correct place to store x,
    // as a child of node p        Q: is it left or right?

    if (x < p-> info)
        insertleft(p,x);
    else
        insertright(p,x);

    return;

}

//insert a new node (with info newval) as left child of place
void BST::insertleft(Tnode *place, string newval)
{
    Tnode *p = new Tnode(newval);

    place -> left = p;
    return;

}

//insert a new node (with info newval) as right child of place
void BST::insertright(Tnode *place, string newval)
{
    Tnode *p = new Tnode(newval);

    place -> right = p;
    return;

}
......................
...............
...............

//
//
void BST::maxleftsubtree()
{
    maxleftsubtree(theroot);
}

//
//
void BST::minrightsubtree()
{
    minrightsubtree(theroot);
}

.....................................
.................................
.........................

//
//
void BST::maxleftsubtree(Tnode *p)
{
    while (p -> left)
        p = p -> right;
    cout << p -> info << " \n";
    return;
}

//
//
void BST::minrightsubtree(Tnode *p)
{
    while (p -> right)
        p = p -> left;
    cout << p -> info << " \n";
    return;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: As a suggestion, you'll probably find it easier to write functions that find the maximum and minimum elements in a subtree, and then call those on the left and right children of the root, respectively.

Comment: The errors says "Assign6_BST.exe has stopped working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your `maxleftsubtree`(`maxtrightsubtree`) function. You should first select the left(right) subtree of the root, the walk along the right(left) branch to the end. Here is a modified version:

```
void BST::maxleftsubtree(Tnode *p)
{
    Tnode* left = NULL;
    if (p != NULL) {
        left = p->left;
    }
    if (left != NULL) {
        while (left->right) 
            left = left -> right;
        cout << left -> info << " \n";
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: so here in that first line of code in the function, you are assigning p, that is originally pointing to the root, to the left node on the tree?

Comment: @123me No, the intention is to assign the left node of p to pointer "left", if p is not NULL.

Comment: OK I see, it had me confused. Thank you for making it clearer

Comment: instead of writing that first line of code ... that means the same as: if (p != NULL)
        left = p -> left;

Comment: @123me Yes, they have the same meaning.